# Question about analyzing lose and accuracy chart

Tags: python, deep-learning

To solve a problem I developed some deep learning models such as MLP (6 Dense layers), CNN (1 Conv1D + 1 Dense layers), LSTM (1 LSTM + 2 Dense layers) and constructed their lose and accuracy chart.

**CNN model**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) + 1,
                    64,  # Embedding size
                    input_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGHT))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(5))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

I have these questions:

1-Which epoche is suitable for each one?

- Chart 1 => 16
- Chart 2 => 15
- Chart 3 => 5

2-Are these charts show overfit? (especially chart 1. what wrong with it? how it can possible the accuracy of the test is more than train!?)

3-is it ok when training loss is higher than test loss (in chart 1)?! should I increase the epoch?

**Chart 1:**

[image]

**Chart 2:**

[image]

**Chart 3:**

[image]

Comment: What charting module/library are you using? Where's your code? What do you mean "over-fit"?

Comment: @martineau I used Keras. I want to analyze the result chart. is it important to show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model seemed to be overfit in chart-1.If you can't increase the dataset(directly or by data augmentation technique) then chart-3 seemed to be the best model among the three.